# Волновое уравнение - проблема реализации

Tags: численные-методы

Задача: решить уравнение колебания струны методом конечных разностей.
Условие устойчивости:

```
dt = dx/(2*A);
```

Первое начальное условие (функция натяжения струны):

```
Uprev = UAllocate(n);
```

(`UAllocate()` - функция распределения значений).
Второе начальное условие:

```
for (int i=0;i<=n;i++) Ubeg[i] = Uprev[i]+dt;
```

(из уравнения `du/dt=f(x)`, `f(x)=1`);

Конечно-разностная схема:

```
for (int i=1; i<n-1; i++){
    Unext[i]=(A*A)*(dt*dt)/(dx*dx)*(a[i+1]-2*a[i]+a[i-1])+2*a[i]-Uprev[i];
    //qDebug()<<Unext[i];
}
```

Так вот, при расчётах получаются какие-то неадекватные значения, уходящие в минус бесконечность. Что здесь не так?

Comment: Возьмите отладчик и посмотрите какая часть ваших вычислений выдает погоду на марсе.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вы хотите сказать, что проблема не в конечно-разностной схеме? Тут выдавать "погоду на Марсе" может только эта часть.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, следует разделять математическую модель и программную, ибо задачи и источники ошибок у них разные. Попробуйте абстрагироваться от кода и проверить корректность мат.модели, а затем транслировать её в код, опять же с проверкой на корректность.

Comment: Я хочу сказать что у вас десяток мат. операций и глючить все вместе они вряд ли могут. Задача сводится к поиску части выражения, которая выдает явную лажу.

Answer (score 0):

Без полного листинга программы понять точно, что происходит — невозможно. Но чаще всего проблема в критерии устойчивости.

Если принимать шаг по времени `dt` равным **точно** тому значению, которое говорит усточивость по теории, то при работе с практической реализацией могут возникнуть проблемы.

Поэтому, велика вероятность получить вменяемые вычисление если добавить в код:

```
 dt*=0.99;
```

делая **мааааленькую коррекцию**. Очень часто это все, что нужно для решения проблем в таких задачах и то, для чего и нужны практические лабораторные работы по численным методам в добавок к теоретическим занятиям.

Дополнительно стоит посмотреть:

- используется ли `double` или `float` и проверить не станет ли все работать при замене одинарной точнсти на двойную. Если станет — то уже копать в этом направлении.
- часто ошибки идут в граничных условиях, недостаточной размерности массива (на 1-2 элемента границы)